# How can a Discord bot listen to old buttons?

Tags: button, discord.js

There is an embed with buttons posted using a bot X, how can i set the bot Y to listen to clicks on those buttons?

So far i tried creating bot and the button file. and setting the `button.data.name` to be the custom id for the original button.

#### `button.js`

```js
const { Events, ButtonInteraction } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: '{1:1004078810158866463}'
    },
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {Client} client 
     */
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if ( interaction.channel.id !== '1004066286101344376') return;
        // if (!interaction.isButton) return;

        interaction.reply({
            ephemeral: true,
            content: `Button clicked: ${interaction.customId}`
        })
    }
}
```

#### `handleComponents.js`

```js
const { loadFiles } = require('../functions/fileLoader');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleComponents = async () => {
        componentFiles = await loadFiles('components');

        const { buttons } = client;
        const buttonsTable = []
        
        await componentFiles.forEach(async file => {
            try {
                const button = await require(file);
                buttons.set(button.data.name, button);

                buttonsTable.push({Button: button.data.name, Status: '✅'});
            } catch (e) {
                buttonsTable.push({Button: file.split('/').pop().slice(0,-3), Status: '❗️'});
                console.error(e);
            }
        })

        console.table(buttonsTable);
    }
}
```

#### `interactionCreate.js`

```js
const { 
    Events,
    ChatInputCommandInteraction,
    codeBlock
 } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    /**
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {Client} client
     */
    async execute(interaction,client) {
        if(interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {...} 
        else if (interaction.isButton) {

            const replyMessages = {
                noCode: 'There is no code for this button.',
                error:  'Error trying to execute button'
            }

            const { buttons } = client;
            const { customId } = interaction;
            const button = await buttons.get(customId);

            if (!button) {
                interaction.reply({
                    ephemeral: true,
                    content: replyMessages.noCode
                })
                return new Error('There is no code for this button.')
            };

            try {
                await button.execute(interaction, client)
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);

                if(interaction.user.id === '1234') replyMessages.error.concat('\n', codeBlock(e));

                interaction.reply({
                    ephemeral: true,
                    content: replyMessages.error
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, as bots only receive interaction events from components created by themselves. It would be insecure otherwise, as random bots could be sniffing into your bot's user's interaction data.

If you want to simulate this behavior, a better option might be using reactions, as those can be listened to by other bots.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks.
Unfortunately i guess i will have to rewrite embeds so my bot can send them itself, i have my files as `json` format, would you happen to know any way to convert that into an embed on `discord.js`?